# How to create selector for function with optional parameter in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need to create a timer like this:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(dismissNotification(completion:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func dismissNotification(completion: (() -> ())? = nil) { ... }
```

but it crashes without displaying any reason. Why it happens? And how to workaround this?

Answer (score 4):

`(NS)Timer`allows only two types of actions:

Without a parameter

- `func timerFireMethod()`

With a single parameter passing the affected `(NS)Timer` instance

- `func timerFireMethod(_ timer : Timer)`

However in iOS 10 / macOS 10.12 you can use a new API with a closure

```
class func scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval interval: TimeInterval, 
                                            repeats: Bool, 
                                              block: @escaping (Timer) -> Void) -> Timer
```

Answer (score 2):

The function crashes because the timer passes itself to the selector method. And the selector method expects an anonymous function.

One thing you can do is this:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(dismissNotification(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func dismissNotification(timer: Timer) {
    //call dismissNotification(completion) here
}
func dismissNotification(completion: (() -> ())? = nil) { ... }
```

Also, you can pass additional data to the `dismissNotification(timer: Timer)` function using the `Timer.userInfo` property.

Comment: you are right, i was trying to avoid creating another function for the same purpose, but I have to:(

Answer (score 1):

The completion handler needs to have the signature

```
 func dismissNotification(completion: Timer) { ... }
```

It is also possible to omit the `Timer` parameter:

```
 func dismissNotification() { ... }
```

`Dispatch` also provides similar functionality allowing the code to be executed on an arbitrary queue:

```
// It's necessary to keep a reference to timer
let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: DispatchTime.now(), interval: DispatchTime.seconds(2))
timer.setEventHandler() { ... } 
timer.resume()
```